# Parse date str in Python into a date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dates of the following format in a file: "9/15/2021 1:36:05 PM".

I am trying to parse them:

```
row = {"Last Updated": "9/15/2021 1:36:05 PM"}
date_3 = datetime.strptime(row['Last Updated'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%m:%S')
```

Its giving me a error:

```
error: redefinition of group name 'm' as group 5; was group 2 at position 116
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, Please show us what the error you are getting is, and what you did to try and resolve it so we can help you.

Comment: You need `%p` in the end to handle `PM` (that also requires replacing `%H` with `%I`).

Comment: Also, `9/15/2021` cannot be `%d/%m/%Y`, only `%m/%d/%Y`.

Answer (score 1):

For date input "9/15/2021 1:36:05 PM" need to replace %H with %I (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12] and add %p flag for the AM/PM marker.

For more details see [datetime.strptime() format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

**Try:**

```
from datetime import datetime

row = {'Last Updated': "9/15/2021 1:36:05 PM"}

date_3 = datetime.strptime(row['Last Updated'], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(date_3)
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-15 13:36:05
```

Comment: date_1 = datetime.strptime('9/1/2021', '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_2 = datetime.strptime('9/11/2021', '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_3 = datetime.strptime(row['Last Updated'], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    
    print ("CHECKING DATE RANGE: " + row['Last Updated'])
    if date_1 < date_3 < date_2:
      print ("YES -> " + row['Last Updated'])
    else:
      print ("NO -> " + row['Last Updated'])

Comment: @uniquemagicshop date '9/1/2021' should use '%m/%d/%Y' assuming month is September.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing %M (minute) and %m (month).

Comment: date_1 = datetime.strptime('9/1/2021', '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_2 = datetime.strptime('9/11/2021', '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_3 = datetime.strptime(row['Last Updated'], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    
    print ("CHECKING DATE RANGE: " + row['Last Updated'])
    if date_1 < date_3 < date_2:
      print ("YES -> " + row['Last Updated'])
    else:
      print ("NO -> " + row['Last Updated'])